# ORACLE Get the first record

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have a table with an specific id.

I need to return the first record of each object id but I have a priority. If there is a 7, use it. If not use a 4. If there are neither of those, use the 6. On my select statement I just given an order.

Looks like data is retrieving me more than one objectid at the same date-time (even hour). I need to display one record only but taking by priority 7,6 and 4 `obs_typeid`.

```
  SELECT 
        r.OBJECTID AS OBJECTID,
        r.DATETIMEUTC as DATETIME_UTC,
        r.OBS_TYPEID
        FROM PROD.WX_RAW r 
        WHERE  r.REPORTTYPE ='FM-15' 
        AND  OBS_TYPEID IN('7','4','6')
        AND r.DATETIMEUTC BETWEEN v_start_date AND v_end_date 
        ORDER BY DECODE (r.OBS_TYPEID,'7',1, '4',2, '6',3,4)
```

Regards

Example data:

```
object id.  datetime.               obs_typeid
10000355147 1/1/2000 3:00:00 PM 4.  (this is good because doesn't have duplicate date).
10000355147 1/5/2000 6:00:00 AM 7.  (this is good 7 is priority)
10000355147 1/7/2000 6:00:00 AM 4.  (bad row, 7 row already exists shouldn't be here).
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT OBJECTID, DATETIME_UTC, OBS_TYPEID
FROM (SELECT r.OBJECTID AS OBJECTID, r.DATETIMEUTC as DATETIME_UTC, r.OBS_TYPEID,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.OBJECTID
                                ORDER BY CASE r.OBS_TYPEID WHEN '7' THEN 1 WHEN '4' THEN 2 WHEN '6' THEN 3 ELSE 4
                                         END) as seqnum
      FROM PROD.WX_RAW r 
      WHERE r.REPORTTYPE = 'FM-15' AND
            r.OBS_TYPEID IN ('7', '4', '6') AND
            r.DATETIMEUTC BETWEEN v_start_date AND v_end_date 
     ) r
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

You'll notice that I also prefer the Standard SQL `case` expressions to bespoke logic such as `DECODE()`.